# Conditionally receiving an synchronous or asynchronous object in controller (angular, ionic)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, ionic-framework

I have the following controller:

```
.controller('SponsorsCtrl', function ($scope, Sponsors, $http) {
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function () {
        Sponsors.all($http).then(function (data) {
                $scope.sponsors = data;
                var check = "check";
                })       
    });
})
```

The reason for using "then" is because I received an asynchronous object. Now I can however also receive a synchronous object via the following service:
(function(){
    angular
        .module('sponsors.services', [])
        .factory('Sponsors', Sponsors);

```
Sponsors.$inject = [];

function Sponsors() {

    var service = {
        all: all,
        allServer: allServer,
        allLocal: allLocal,
        get: get,
        getTimeStamp: getTimeStamp
    };
    return service;

    function all($http) {
        var timeDifference = (Date.now() - this.getTimeStamp());

        if (timeDifference < 600000) {
            return this.allLocal();
        }
        else {                
            return this.allServer($http);       
        }
    }

    function allServer($http) {
        return $http.get("http://dream16backend.azurewebsites.net/api/dream16/sponsors")
                    .then(function (resp) {
                        //Set localstorage, create timestamp and return the data
                        window.localStorage.setItem('sponsors', resp.data);
                        window.localStorage.setItem('sponsorsTimeStamp', Date.now());
                        var bla = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('sponsors'));
                        return bla;
                    }, function(err) {
                        console.log('ERR', err);
                    });            
    }

    function allLocal() {
        return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('sponsors'));
    }

    function get(adressId) {
        for (var i = 0; i < sponsors.length; i++) {
            if (sponsors[i].id === parseInt(sponsorId)) {
                return sponsors[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    function getTimeStamp() {           
        return window.localStorage.getItem('sponsorsTimeStamp');
    }
}
```

})();
This way only the async call (function allServer) works, but the sync fails becaus: `Sponsors.all(...).then is not a function`

then I thought the fix was to move the "then" functionality to the all function in the service. This makes the sync call (function allLocal) work, but now the async call fails. The else condition now looks like this:

```
else {
                this.allServer($http).then(function (data) {
                    return data;
                })
            }
```

And the controller looks like:

```
.controller('SponsorsCtrl', function ($scope, Sponsors, $http) {
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function () {
        $scope.sponsors = Sponsors.all($http);
        var check = "check"; 
    });
})
```

I verified that the call itself is working (via test variable "bla"). I also see that the controller the controller runs var check = "check"; before running the async code. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Much simpler to inject `$http` in service instead of passing it as argument for every method and no need to inject in controller. Note that first `then` of `$http` returns a response object that has a `data` property you need to access for the actual server response

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the tip on the $http, but I am i actually extract the data out of the response via the allServer function. I have verified that the object returned by `this.allServer($http);` is in fact the correct data. The problem is that my controller is executing before receiving the async service result

Answer (score 1):

OK...so you need to return a promise for both instances of `Sponsors.all()` since one instance is already returning `$http` promise.

Inject `$q` in service so that `allLocal()` will also return a promise.

```
function allLocal() {
    return $q.resolve(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('sponsors')));
}
```

And in controller you need to use `then()`

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function () {
    Sponsors.all($http).then(function(data){
       $scope.sponsors = data;
    });
    var check = "check"; 
});
```

As mentioned in comments above there is no need to inject `$http` in controller and pass it to service when it would be simpler to just inject `$http` in service where it is actually needed

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose you the following solution. In both cases return "Promise" object. For `allLocal` function it will look like this:

```
function allLocal() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('sponsors')));
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

So now you can use `.then` in both cases - sync and async

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend injecting the $http service into your service.. I.e.

```
.factory('MyService', function ($http, $timeout,$q) {
    var service = {
            all: all,
            allServer: allServer,
            allLocal: allLocal,
            get: get,
            getTimeStamp: getTimeStamp
        };
        return service;

        function all() {
            var timeDifference = (Date.now() - this.getTimeStamp());

            if (timeDifference < 600000) {
                return this.allLocal();
            }
            else {                
                return this.allServer($http);       
            }
        }

        function allServer() {
            return $http.get("http://dream16backend.azurewebsites.net/api/dream16/sponsors")
                        .then(function (resp) {
                            //Set localstorage, create timestamp and return the data
                            window.localStorage.setItem('sponsors', resp.data);
                            window.localStorage.setItem('sponsorsTimeStamp', Date.now());
                            var bla = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('sponsors'));
                            return bla;
                        }, function(err) {
                            console.log('ERR', err);
                        });            
        }

        function allLocal() {
            var dfd = $q.defer();   //create a deferred object
            $timeout(function(){
               var localResponse = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('sponsors'));; 
               dfd.resolve(localResponse);   //resolve the localObject
            });
            return dfd.promise;  //return the promise object so controller gets the .then function
        }

        function get(adressId) {
            for (var i = 0; i < sponsors.length; i++) {
                if (sponsors[i].id === parseInt(sponsorId)) {
                    return sponsors[i];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        function getTimeStamp() {           
            return window.localStorage.getItem('sponsorsTimeStamp');
        }
})
```

Comment: This is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with a service that may or may not return a promise, you can use `$q.when(...)` to wrap that API call and let `$q` handle the rest.

In your case all you have to do is wrap your service api like so `$q.when(Sponsors.all($http))` and use it as any regular promise.

check out https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promise-methods.